# How to make a Menu that Starts static and then scrolls with you?

Tags: menu, static, scroll, floating, motion

How would a create a menu that starts off static but then starts to scroll with you when you reach a certain point in a page?

EXAMPLES:

http://techcrunch.com/

http://www.beyonceonline.com

Comment: Not really understanding what you're saying. Both of those pages have static horizontal header ontop, and to me they dont move.

Comment: When you scroll down it seems to follow you even though it starts off static but then becomes fixed. At least that feels more apparent in the second link. Sorry when I mean move I don't mean the menu is animated or in motion but it follows your scroll. Don't know if that made it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess making the menu a fixed div in your head tag, making the content a 100%x100% dynamic div with a 50px top margin (the menu should be no more than 50px tall, but that's just my opinion), then setting the menu z-index= 1; and the content z-index= -1; in your css.